# ¿Cómo obtener campos de 3 tablas combinadas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

No se sacar el iva acumulado por linea que tiene cada producto (tabla_productos) en la tabla_pedido (sumar todos los 4%, todos los 10% y todos los 21% por linea).

- Tabla_productos

  > ```
  > id    | nombre    | iva | precio
  > 1     | Producto1 | 4   | 20 
  > 2     | Producto2 | 10  | 50
  > ```
- Tabla lineas_pedido

  > ```
  > id    | pedido  | id_producto | unidades  | total
  > 1     | 100     | 1           | 1         | 20
  > 2     | 100     | 2           | 1         | 50
  > 3     | 101     | 1           | 1         | 20
  > ```

Quiero conseguir el siguiente resultado desglosado por tipo de IVA:

> ```
> pedido  | iva4 | iva10 | iva21 | total
> 100     | 0.16 | 5     | 0     | 70
> 101     | 0.16 | 0     | 0     | 20
> ```

El total es la suma de los items de la tabla_pedido, esto si se scarlo.
Lo que **no se sacar el iva acumulado por linea que tiene cada producto** de la tabla_pedido (sumar todos los 4%, todos los 10% y todos los 21% por linea).

Comment: Que has intentado? Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: @anonimo no te entiendo, por favor lee  cómo contestar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Muestra la consulta que estás usando y si la misma da error indícanos también cuál es el error que da. Pulsa [edit] para mejorar la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Me refiero a que edites y muestres lo que has intentado

Comment: @AntonioRuiz Hacer un comentario es diferente a una respuesta, el "por favor lee como contestar..." es inadecuado en la sección comentarios de la pregunta, tendría sentido que apareciese en la sección de comentarios de alguna respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás buscando algo así:

```
SELECT pedido,
  SUM(IF(iva=4,precio*unidades*iva/100,0)) iva4,
  SUM(IF(iva=10,precio*unidades*iva/100,0)) iva10,
  SUM(IF(iva=21,precio*unidades*iva/100,0)) iva21,
  SUM(precio*unidades) total
  FROM productos JOIN lineas_pedido ON id_producto=productos.id
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Para que el sitio funcione correctamente (y de paso no nos puntúen negativamente ni a ti ni a mí), debes modificar tu pregunta incorporando la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Te envío el modelo que he tenido que generar para encontrar la solución y veas cómo facilitarnos en el futuro la tarea de responderte:

```
CREATE TABLE productos (
  id INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(31),
  iva INT,
  precio FLOAT
);

CREATE TABLE lineas_pedido (
  id INT,
  pedido INT,
  id_producto INT,
  unidades INT,
  total INT
);

INSERT INTO productos VALUES
(1, 'Producto1', 4, 20),
(2, 'Producto2', 10, 50);

INSERT INTO lineas_pedido VALUES
(1, 100, 1, 1, 20),
(2, 100, 2, 1, 50),
(3, 101, 1, 1, 20);
```

Por cierto, para esos datos, el resultado esperado sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si además incorporas a tu pregunta el código de tu intento, podremos ayudarte a localizar qué te ha impedido resolver el problema. El SQL parece fácil, pero tiene varios conceptos algo escurridizos, te animo a seguir preguntando hasta que lo domines.

Espero haberte ayudado con esta duda concreta y a formular preguntas en Stackoverflow. Ánimo con ello.

Answer (score 0):

no se como esta la consulta pero esto podria darte una idea

```html
selec i4.pedido as pedido, i4.iva as iva4, i10.iva as iva10, i21.iva as iva21 
from (` consulta para sacar pedido, sum(iva) as iva | iva=4`) as i4 
inner join (`consulta para sacar pedido, sum(iva) as iva | iva=10`) as i10 on i4.pedido=i10.pedido 
inner join (`consulta para sacar pedido, sum(iva) as iva | iva=21`) as i21 on i4.pedido=i21.pedido group by pedido;
```

**si ya puedes sacar la suma solo te falta juntalo**

Comment: Cuando la pregunta está mal planteada no se debe responder y esperar a que el OP. La mejore